# Why use curl instead of other methods?

Tags: php, libcurl

I would like to know why it is better to use **curl** instead off other methods like
**$ret=file($url)** in php. 
This is actually used to **access an http api** for an sms gateway.

Someone dropped a "I would recommend using curl for http connections", but I don't know why.

I just read that it is necessary for Paypal payments, so that does sound interesting.

I did a Google search "why use libcurl", but I haven't found an answer yet.

Could someone explain please?

Comment: I would love to know the performance of both methods if anyone knows them/ has has an idea

Comment: Yes, I got this link for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555523/filegetconte...ter-performance

Comment: @Richard the link in your comment is broken

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the FAQ on the [curl site](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#What_is_cURL) says it best:

> **1.2 What is libcurl?**
>
> libcurl is a reliable and portable
>   library which provides you with an
>   easy interface to a range of common
>   Internet protocols.
>
> You can use libcurl for free in your
>   application, be it open source,
>   commercial or closed-source.
>
> libcurl is most probably the most
>   portable, most powerful and most often
>   used C-based multi-platform file
>   transfer library on this planet - be
>   it open source or commercial.

Also, curl facilitates downloading data from multiple sources simultaneously with better efficiency than say `file_get_contents()` or `file()`.

Comment: Also, when developing a recent PHP application, I was looking for a way to download data from multiple sources simultaneously. My original approach had been sequential, and took a very long time. Using curl I was able to set up an array of multiple connections, and execute them concurrently. Sort of like multi-threading.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't know much about other methods of doing HTTP calls in PHP, so I'm not sure if they can do this or not, but Curl can mimic a web browser in pretty much every way, by setting headers, even the user-agent header, etc so that the web server just thinks its a browser which can be important as some sites will try to stop access from anything that isn't a traditional browser

Answer (score 1):

Curl extension has a lot of options that you can set, for example the connection time out. You can also add post variables or access the site with a specific referer. I also reccomend you to use CURL.

Comment: thanks, I am reading up on it
connections are also faster then file or file_get_contents
I will definitivly start to use CURL then